# Select less frequent elements from list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, min

I would appreciate some help with this problem. I have a list with multiple elements and I want to select de element with the lowest frequency. If multiple elements have the lowest frequency, I have to return them all.

For example:
list1 = [1,2,2,2,3]
I have to return 1 and 3
I tried using min(list1, key = list1.count)) but this return 1 only
I am using Python 3.10

Edit: I am not allowed to use import

Answer (score 0):

I think this question can be answered with more google research by yourself. But let me help you in some understanding.

1. If you really need any help from the Algorithm side, then there are multiple approaches like using a Hashmap to find the elements in O(n) time and space. You can also sort the array to perform the operation in O(nlgn) time but in constant space.
2. If you are trying to find some python oneliner, then I would say don't because most these one liners are deceiving. They tend to very clean but cost time in the background.

In your case `max` or `min` is designed to get a single element. Hence you get only one result. However you can build upon the following code

```py
sorted(list1, key=list1.count)
```

**Edit 1:** What do you mean that you are not allowed to use import. Is it some kind of interview/homework question? You shouldn't ask for homework solutions in total at SO.